# how to give relative path into href if xsl:import

Tags: xslt

I am using xslt 1.0.

I want to import A.xsl into B.xsl.

I am unable to use relative paths in href attribute of xsl:import. for ex. path is c:/test/testdata/xsl/file/A.xsl

I tired following code

```
 <xsl:variable name="filePath" select="concat(Systemprop:getProperty('docRootPath'),'/xsl/file/A.xsl')" />
```

and 
    `<xsl:import href="{concat(Systemprop:getProperty('docRootPath'),'/xsl/file/A.xsl')}">`

where docrootPath = c:/test/testdata

but its is giving error : Element type "xsl:variable" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".

but its giving me :Had IO Exception with stylesheet file. Please suggest .

Answer (score 0):

See the spec, http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Combining-Stylesheets, it defines the syntax for include and import as

```
<!-- Category: top-level-element -->
<xsl:include
  href = uri-reference />

<xsl:import
  href = uri-reference />
```

So the `href` attribute value needs to be a URI reference, neither an expression nor an attribute value template is allowed there. So putting in an XPath expression like `concat(...)` is not possible, is not supported.

A relative URI reference can be used of course, but you would need to make sure a base URI is defined properly, for instance doing `<xsl:import xml:base="file:///C:/test/testdata/" href="file.xml"/>`. That is however also only a static value to be defined during stylesheet authoring.

Comment: Hi , thank you much for your answer but my problem is I can not use xml :base as I am using XSLT 1.0. Any other solutions ??

Comment: With a single stylesheet I don't see a way, it should be possible to use a pre transformation step that creates the XSLT with the `href` values you want. That step could also use XSLT.